# MySQL trigger to insert date to row with unique matching ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write an SQL trigger to insert the date into a row of another table after an insert.

The data comes in as such:

A form is submitted to _OnsiteTable which includes a JobID, this JobID matches a current entry containing a JobID value in _JobTable. Upon insert of the data into _OnsiteTable I need a trigger that will insert the current date into a column called JobClosedDate in JobTable.

It needs to insert the date into the row that matches the JobID value entered in the form on _OnsiteTable.

I have this so far but I don't know how to compare the JobID values between tables and insert into the specific row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateClosedDate
AFTER INSERT on _OnsiteTable

BEGIN

Declare ClosedDate DATETIME;
SET ClosedDate = CURDATE();

CASE WHEN (ClosedDate) = ?
    THEN INSERT INTO `_JobTable`( `JobClosedDate`)
    VALUES
    ( ClosedDate);  

END CASE;

END
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Complete query now working, thank you! As below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateClosedDate
AFTER INSERT on _OnsiteTable

BEGIN

Declare ClosedDate DATETIME;
SET ClosedDate = CURDATE();

UPDATE `_JobTable` SET `JobClosedDate` = ClosedDate WHERE `JobID` = new.JobID;

END
```

Comment: Just change the hole case statement with: `update _JobTable set JobClosedDate = ClosedDate where JobID = NEW.JobID;`

Comment: Thanks! @JorgeCampos Actually I'm getting a syntax error, do I need to modify the syntax somewhere on that line for it to be correct?

Comment: It may be because I didn't use the brackets.

Comment: Ah, got it. Needed to put my tables and columns in `` - Just testing now thank you @JorgeCampos

Comment: Let me know if it work then I will add it as an answer :)

Comment: That did it! Just needed to also change to after INSERT. I must have changed this to update by accident.

Comment: Glad to help! Consider in accepting the given answer if you like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem was solved with the given comment I will add it here to reference for others with similar issues:

Since you want to **Update** a column ("*insert a value into a column...*") You just need to fix your trigger changing your current `case` statement to an `update` command as follow:

```
UPDATE `_JobTable` 
   SET `JobClosedDate` = ClosedDate 
 WHERE `JobID` = NEW.JobID;
```